# SQL server mapping table

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have one question how to write one query

Below is a product mapping table sample

```
Seq Product

 1. [N/A]
 2. App
 3. App OTH
 4. Opp FCL
 5. Opp LCL
 6. Opp OTH
 7. OTH
```

I have another table one entry shows several records and sometimes one entry has several Product!

example

```
Seq Entry ProductSales

 1. 7SX3456 [N/A] 
 2. 7SX3456 Opp FCL 
 3. 7SX3456 Opp OTH
```

I want to write a query, the logic is, if the entry Product shows [N/A] then I will search the second Product from the Product matching table that matches the entry's Product. So in this case, I will pick “Opp FCL” as I don’t pick [N/A] and “Opp OTH” comes after “Opp FCL”.

So the Product for this entry I will update as Opp FCL for all records.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read the guides on [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) in order to better understand your question and provide you with even better answers.

Comment: Do you vant to exclude records with `[N/A]` ProductSales values from the query? Or do you want to show only single row?

Comment: I want to exclude [N/A] and keep only one ProductSales for one entry.

Comment: If this is `SQL Server`, why is there `MySQL` tag?  Please remove.

Answer (score 0):

use a common table expression with ROW_NUMBER

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
   SELECT Seq, Entry, ProductSales, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By Entry ORDER BY Seq) AS RN
   FROM ProductSales
   WHERE ProductSales <> '[N/A]'
)
SELECT Seq, Entry, ProductSales
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, how come I didn't think of this!